# What does 'Unnecessary table scan' mean exactly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table of names with Ids

```
Create table Names (
Id int,
Name nvarchar(500)
)
```

I'm trying to create a procedure that would select 1 name that matches the provided Id if Id is provided or select all names if no Id is provided

```
Create Procedure SelectNames
    @Id int = null
AS
BEGIN
    Select * From Names
    Where IsNull(@Id, 0) = 0
    Or Id = @Id
END
GO
```

But I get an error: 'Error: SR0015 : Microsoft.Rules.Data : Deterministic function call (ISNULL) might cause an unnecessary table scan.'

What does the 'unnecessary table scan' refer to in this instance?

And is there a better way to write the procedure?

Comment: Why use `ISNULL` at all, and not just do `WHERE @ID IS NULL OR...`?

Comment: Also, with a "catch-all"/"Kitchen sink" query like this, an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: `````ISNULL````` is for the @Id parameter.  Basically I need to return all rows if the parameter @Id is null, not the ones where the column `````Id````` is null

Comment: *"`ISNULL` is for the @Id parameter. "* I know... But why use it at all; it's not needed. There is are operators for checking if a value is `NULL` or not; `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: If I just use `````Where @Id IS NULL OR @Id = Id````` It only select the rows where `````@Id = Id````` and for some reason it completely ignores `````@Id IS NULL`````

Comment: @Larnu Oh my bad, `````Where @Id IS NULL````` works fine. I've tried `````Where @Id = null````` and that didn't work. So yeah `````ISNULL````` is indeed not needed here.

Comment: That isn't going to happen. If you pass `NULL` for `@ID` then *all* the rows will be returned. `ID = NULL` will *never*  be true so what you state makes no sense.

Comment: ... `Where @Id = null` is *not* `WHERE @ID IS NULL`. `NULL` equals nothing, nor doesn't equal anything; including `NULL`. `= NULL`, `> NULL`, `< NULL`, `<> NULL`, etc will never be TRUE, and will always return UNKNOWN. The only way to compare equality with a `NULL` is using `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: I normally use a `WHERE ID = COALESCE(@ID,ID)` If an @ID is not null, it is used. If @ID is null, the table's ID is used.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to remove the table scan is to create an index (probably unique) on your `Id` column. In general, one wouldn't expect a nullable `Id` value. With that index in place, finding a name by `Id` will not require scanning (or iterating through every row in) the table.

Regarding "better way to write the procedure" - once the nullability is removed, a simple `SELECT` without the `WHERE` should be fine.